# network errror when trying to connect to docker instance (windows 7/docker toolbox)

Tags: windows, docker, windows-7, docker-toolbox

I am trying to use docker for the first time on windows 7. I've gone through several guides and everything seemed to be going well, however I cannot actually connect to the docker container once I run it.

I am trying to connect to `http://192.168.99.100:32769/` however I keep getting the following error;

> Network Error (tcp_error)
>
> A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"
>
> The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.

Below is a screen grab with some information.

[image: docker commands]

Here is a screen grab of the kitematic window;

[image: kitematic]

I've tried running `docker-machine env default` and also the command it says to afterwards, on both cmd/powershell but neither works.

I've tried removing and recreating the docker machine. As well as reinstalling docker completely.

I can't seem to find any information as to why I'm getting this error.

Exact windows version is `Windows 7 Professional`.

Hope someone can help out? If you need any more information please say!

Comment: How do you connect to `http://192.168.99.100:32769/`? With Firefox and Internet Explorer, I can open the url and see the index.html page. But with Edge browser, I cannot.

Comment: @matt9 I've tried with chrome and internet explorer, both return the same error for me

Comment: Can you login to the docker host by executing `docker-machine ssh default` and get the page by `wget -qO- 127.0.0.1:32769`?

Comment: Yes! it returns the html content of the page this way

Comment: So, the nginx container is working. I think the problem might be some network settings of your environment. Try to check your browser settings or ask to a system administrator of your LAN.